# C - Standard Output Printing Order

Tags: c, stdout

The code is as follows:

```
printf("u");
write(STDOUT_FILENO, "m", 1);
printf("d\n");
```

output: mud

Can someone explain why the output is printed in this order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard output is line buffered by default, that means `printf("u")`, will only put the `"u"` in its buffer, until a `fflush` or a new line character is seen. To see the output in order, try this:

```
printf("u");
fflush(stdout);
write(STDOUT_FILENO, "m", 1);
printf("d\n");
```

Comment: No, stdout is not line buffered.  *If* is is associated with a terminal, then it is line buffered by default.  If it is associated with a pipe or a regular file, it most likely is not.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Can you show the reference of that?

Comment: Thanks, it would be more convincing if you could point the relevant sections in the standard, be it C11 or C99 or C89.

Comment: @fluter: C11 Section 7.21.3.7. The C requirement is that `stdin` and `stdout` must not be fully-buffered unless they definitely do not refer to an interactive device (such as a terminal). If it does refer to an interactive device, it can be either line-buffered, or unbuffered. If it does not, then it can be fully-buffered (and, at least on a Unix-like system, probably will be fully-buffered, as @WilliamPursell points out).

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`printf` stores "u" in a buffer. `write` writes data to the underlying filedescritor.  The next `printf` puts "d\n" in the buffer.  At some point in the future (either when the program exits, or when you call `printf` enough that the buffer is full), the buffer will be written to the underlying file descriptor.

Answer (score 1):

Output via the standard C streams is buffered.  The first call to `printf` stored `u` into the buffer, while the second line outputs an `m` directly to the system's standard output file handle via the `write` system call, finally the second call to printf stores `d` and a line feed in the buffer and flushes the buffer to the system standard output handle, either because output is line buffered (which is usually the default if the `FILE*` is associated with a terminal) and `\n` causes the flush or because the stream is flushed upon program normal termination.

`stderr` is unbuffered by default, try this:

```
fprintf(stderr, "u");
write(STDERR_FILENO, "m", 1);
fprintf(stderr, "d\n");
```

Comment: Where is the "terminal" in this question?  Stop conflating stdout with a tty.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: I agree, I changed the answer to be more precise.